# Writing a python code for multiple gaussian functions

Tags: python, gaussian

I'm trying to write a python code that will create plots for multiple identical gaussian functions. In the online graphing calculator it looks like this:

[image: desired output]

But when trying to do it using `numpy` and `matplotlib`, I get the following:

[image: problematic plot in python]

What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

b = 10 ** 6
L = 50
N = 5
sigma = np.power(10, 3)

x = np.linspace(0, L, 1000)

def gaussian(x, dk, sigma):
    return np.exp(-np.power((x - dk) / sigma, 2.) / 2.)

y = 6 * gaussian(np.linspace(0, L, 1000), L / 4., np.power(10., -2.)) + 6 * gaussian(np.linspace(0, L, 1000), L / 2., np.power(10., -2.)) + 6 * gaussian(np.linspace(0, L, 1000), .75 * L, np.power(10., -2.))

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you observe is an sampling artifact.
Let us introduce a parameter called `n_sample`. This parameter gives us the number of points on which the function is evaluated in your given interval.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def gaussian(x,dk,sigma):
    return np.exp(-np.power((x-dk)/sigma,2.) / 2.)

L=50
n_sample=10000
x = np.linspace(0,L,n_sample)
y = 6*gaussian(np.linspace(0,L,n_sample),L/4., np.power(10.,-2.)) + 6*gaussian(np.linspace(0,L,n_sample), L/2., np.power(10.,-2.)) +  6*gaussian(np.linspace(0,L,n_sample), .75*L, np.power(10.,-2.))

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.title("n_sample={}".format(n_sample))
plt.show()
```

I plotted your functions with different values for `n_sample`. 
You see that if you increase `n_sample` to a sufficiently large value, you get a correct representation of your data.

With 10k samples:
[image: 10k]

With 1000 samples:
[image: 1000]

With only 100 samples. Note the changes in the y-scale:
[image: 100]

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in the gaussian function which is not the same as the sample you mentioned. But it is not necessary to said as 'wrong', as it just affect the standard deviation value.

Instead of `np.exp(-np.power((x-dk)/sigma,2.) / 2.)`, it should be

```
np.exp(-np.power((x-dk),2.) /( sigma / 2.))
```

**Edit**: And sigma should be 10^-3 to reproduce the sample provided. But right now I just use 10^-2, as small deviation make things a bit too sensitive.

Sigma will be so small such that the gaussian function will be so sensitive to the sampling size.

But fixing this won't give you the desired result, you will notice under 1000, the middle bar is still a bit lower.

[image: Gauss_3]

Why?

First, you need to notice:

> Gaussian function is not for generating step function in primary purpose.

Lets take a look for a more detail example about sampling, it is a bit related to statistic.

---

N = 100

```
for i in range(50):
    y += 6*gaussian(x, i, np.power(10.,-3.))
```

[image: n_100]

What happens to this graph? Why there is a drop at the middle?

The reason is that gaussian function is an approximation of probability. Lets say human being is wiped out by a new flu. Only 100 people survive, ok, now we choose 50 people out and check how many people is infected (1 of them is inflected).

**So what is the probability of choosing 50 people out of 50 people and how sure we call tell there is one group have someone inflected?**

> Ans: 1, for sure you chose all 50 some of them must be inflected

**So what is the probability of choosing 25 people out of 50 people and how sure we call tell there is one group have someone inflected?**

> Ans: 1/ nCr(50,25) ~= 0

By the way, this time the gaussian function is not a good approximation as for low sampling size. (Due to central limit theorem, [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem))

---

N = 10000

I reduce some sampling point to save time, so

```
for i in range(0, 10000, 100):
    y += 6*gaussian(x, i, np.power(10.,-3.))
```

[image: Gauss_2]

That's the same, for choosing few thousand from few ten thousand it is still hard to tell the difference.

---

For 100 sample, the probability difference of choosing one more people to count is outstanding.

49 out of 50, and 48 of 50 make big difference, as in total the pool has just 100 people.

But for 10000, 49 out of 50 and 48 out of 50, who care? They are almost the same of that huge pool. That's **why you can make three bars with same height**.

P.S. What I mention is basically the idea of Central Limit Theorem, why when the pool is large, sampling size won't make big difference to telling the true, and that's why we can do "sampling" to represent the whole pool.

Comment: I don't think that your "correction" of the gaussian is correct. Your new definition does not square the standard deviation `sigma` and you divide by `sigma/2` instead of `2*sigma^2`.

Comment: @Merlin1896 , originally, yes, sigma should be squared. But pls take a look for the sample of OP, it is using (x-k)^2/ 0.0005, to reproduce the one with parameter that OP want, 10^-3/2 is already 0.0005, 10^-2 ^ 2 * 2 is 0.0002. But I do forget to mention I should change `np.power(10., -2.)` to `np.power(10., -3.)` in this case. No matter what, it just change the deviation of distribution, making it more sensitive or not.

Comment: But you are right, I should not said original function is wrong, it is just not the same  as the sample.